# MariaDB/MySQL - Convert keys and values from json object into rows, using JSON_TABLE

Tags: json, mariadb

Using Mariadb 10.6 - In the following example, I try to convert the entries of the json object into table rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM JSON_TABLE('{ 
   "1": [1, 123.25], 
   "10": [2, 110.5], 
   "100": [3, 105.75] 
}', '$.*' COLUMNS (
    col1 decimal(13,2) PATH '$',
    col2 int PATH '$[0]',
    col3 decimal(17,2) PATH '$[1]'
)) table1
```

The result is:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | 1 | 123.25 |
| NULL | 2 | 110.50 |
| NULL | 3 | 105.75 |

Is there any way to fill "col1" with the property keys ("1", "10", "100")?

I guess there is some "key word" to reference the key, but I can't find any information on this in the docs from MariaDB or MySQL.

I already made a routine that creates a temporary table by looping output from `JSON_KEYS`, but it would be more elegant if I can use `JSON_TABLE` for this job.

Comment: There is actually a task for this at MariaDB development: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-30145

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it without routines:

- extract your json values using [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table), alongside a row number using `FOR ORDINALITY`
- extract your keys using [`JSON_KEYS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-keys)
- for each record, extract the i-th key corresponding to i-th ranking value, given by row number, using [`JSON_EXTRACT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract)

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_KEYS(@json), 
                    CONCAT('$[', table1.rowid-1, ']')) AS col1, 
       table1.col2,
       table1.col3
FROM JSON_TABLE(@json, '$.*' COLUMNS (
    rowid FOR ORDINALITY,
    col2 int PATH '$[0]',
    col3 decimal(17,2) PATH '$[1]'
)) table1
```

Output:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "1" | 1 | 123.25 |
| "10" | 2 | 110.50 |
| "100" | 3 | 105.75 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6zyB9qS1DAk55MzdVMgVm3/0).

Comment: This is a good workaround, but I find it hard to believe that there is'nt any build-in functionality in JSON_TABLE to solve this task.

Comment: If someone will post a query while using `JSON_TABLE` only, I will be learning with you. As far as I've tried, it became messier due to subqueries.

Answer (score 2):

This is an other way to do it using `CROSS JOIN`, `JSON_TABLE` & `JSON_KEYS`:

`JSON_KEYS(json)` will give us `["1", "10", "100"]`

`CROSS JOIN` is used to generate multi rows from `["1", "10", "100"]`

```
WITH data AS
( 
 SELECT '{
           "1": [1, 123.25], 
           "10": [2, 110.5], 
           "100": [3, 105.75] 
         }' AS json
)
SELECT k.key, c.col2, c.col3
  FROM data
 CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
                       JSON_KEYS(json), 
                       '$[*]' COLUMNS(
                                       rowid FOR ORDINALITY, 
                                       key TEXT PATH '$'
                                      )
                      ) k
 INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT cols.*
      FROM data,
           JSON_TABLE(
                      json,
                      '$.*' COLUMNS(
                                     rowid FOR ORDINALITY,
                                     col2 int PATH '$[0]',
                                     col3 decimal(17, 2) PATH '$[1]'
                                    )
                      ) AS cols) AS c
    ON c.rowid = k.rowid;
```

[demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/k80GEePE)

Answer (score 1):

I answer to my own question:
I'm sorry that there apparently is'nt any native option to reference the key names in a json object with `JSON_TABLE` (yet), and the two workarounds currently posted are great.
I ended up using a mixture from both:

```
SET @json = '{ "1": [1, 123.25], "10": [2, 110.5], "100": [3, 105.75] }';

SELECT
    col1,
    JSON_EXTRACT(@json, CONCAT('$."', col1, '"[0]')) col2,
    JSON_EXTRACT(@json, CONCAT('$."', col1, '"[1]')) col3
FROM JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(@json), '$[*]' COLUMNS (col1 varchar(20) PATH '$')) t1;
```

Comment: Although this doesn't look like a scalable solution... If tomorrow you happen to have 20 columns in your json, would you use 20 `JSON_EXTRACT`?

Comment: @lemon You're right, in that case I would probably use your solution. Also, if there was many rows, it would be a better solution. But for my use case, the datasets are like in my example, and therefore my answer seems to be the least complex/most efficient.